# Regex Curly brackets not working properly

Tags: .net, regex, progress-4gl

I have the following problem:

I am working with openedge Progress-4gl, version 11.3. 
I am trying to use a regex to check if the entered string is valid according to our requirments.

The string should be exactly 6 characters long, with only numbers. So I came to this regex: ^[0-9]{6}$.
According to online regex testers it should work.

Now when I use this regex in progress, it is as if the {6} part is simply ignored/removed.

Full code:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE regexp               AS CLASS System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex NO-UNDO.
regexp = NEW System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^[0-9]{6}$").
IF NOT regexp:IsMatch(objKonprest:orderref) THEN
DO:
    MESSAGE "Orderref is not valid!"
           VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
end.
```

The objkonprest:orderref can be any string, but with the code above the ismatch will always return false unless it is a 1 character number.

Does anyone have experience with this kind of problem? I could solve it using following regex: ^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$, but that is just silly.

Edit: added the real code

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You should post your real code and real pattern, don't remove the extra characters.

Comment: Modified it to show the real code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because {} has special meaning in ABL. Just escape { and }.
Modified code:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE regexp               AS CLASS System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex NO-UNDO.
regexp = NEW System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^[0-9]~{6~}$").
IF NOT regexp:IsMatch(objKonprest:orderref) THEN
DO:
    MESSAGE "Orderref is not valid!"
           VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
end.
```

Comment: Works like a charm! I didn't know those had to be escaped. Thanks alot!